# Resto is 12.7 and method getTagli return 10.0 , 2.0 , 0.5 but my result had to be 10.0, 2.0, 0.5, 0.2

Tags: java, binary, double, approximation, calculation

> Is easy, have two collections set (list) and tagli; scroll list and when resto> item in list, pickup that item and subtract that item until resto is equal 0.

```
public static ArrayList<Double> getTagli(Double resto) {
    Set list = Cassa.getSoldi().keySet();   // 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1
    Iterator iter = list.iterator();
    Double divisore = (Double) iter.next();
    while (iter.hasNext() && resto > 0) {
        resto = Cassa.divisioniSuccessive(resto, divisore);
        if (resto<divisore)
            divisore = (Double) iter.next();
    }
    return tagli;
}

private static Double divisioniSuccessive(Double dividendo, Double divisore) {
    if (dividendo >= divisore) {
        tagli.add(divisore);
        dividendo = (Double) dividendo - (Double) divisore;
    }
    return dividendo;
}
```

Comment: Please add some more clarity. This question is extremely difficult to understand.

Comment: in the debug stage at some point resto = 2.6999999999999993 e non 2.7

Comment: ho risolto ho arrotondato tutti i double alla 2 cifra decimale

Comment: public double arrotonda( double numero, int nCifreDecimali ){
    return Math.round( numero * Math.pow( 10, nCifreDecimali ) )/Math.pow( 10, nCifreDecimali );
}

Answer (score -1):

```
public static double arrotonda( double numero, int nCifreDecimali ){
    return Math.round( numero * Math.pow( 10, nCifreDecimali ) )/Math.pow( 10, nCifreDecimali );
}
```

Comment: Please format this properly. Also, please provide some explanation as to how this works as code-only answers are discouraged here.